# we are not able to open images with the space in their names Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, tomcat8, tomcat9

In our Tomcat-Java Application, we are not able to open images with the space in their names, noticed %20 in the URL is not being replaced with space while loading the image. I have tried adding below lines in bold to the connector tag in Tomcat server.xml file but no luck. Can somebody please suggest on this ? Appreciate your help in advance.

FYI…

Tomcat version:  8.5.57

```
<Connector port="8082" protocol="HTTP/1.1"

               connectionTimeout="20000"

               redirectPort="8445"

               URIEncoding="UTF-8"

               useBodyEncodingForURI="true" />
```

Comment: How are you trying to open the files? Can you post code?

Answer (score 0):

Use `URLDecoder.decode(query parameter)`

Comment: Should I place this as is in the connector tag ? Like below <Connector port="8082" protocol="HTTP/1.1"

               connectionTimeout="20000"

               redirectPort="8445"

              URLDecoder.decode(query parameter)  />

Comment: No, use it where you read the query parameters in the code.

Comment: can we fix this at the tomcat level ?

Comment: Can I have any suggestion, please?